# Generate two random number between 1 and 10 and run a do while loop while they not equal, my code runs but i dont want the numbers to be ever equal

Tags: java

*i made some changes in my variable but still a and b will be the same at one point and the random number have to be unique cant be repeated*

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        do
        {
            a = (int)((Math.random()*10)+1);// a number between 1 and 10
            b = (int) ((Math.random()*10)+1);
            System.out.print(a + " " +b);    
        }
        while(a != b);
    }
```

Comment: Look at your condition *carefully*. It says to run that loop while `a` is NOT EQUAL to `b`. Your requirement is the opposite. You also never even modify `a` and `b` in your loop.

Comment: thank you, i noticed that... sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

`while (rand == randT)` surely? On the basis that `a` and `b` don't change, plus the fact that you are using `!=` instead of `==`.